# Write a function that takes a list of strings an prints them, one per line, in a rectangular frame. need minor editing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote:

```
p=input("words?")
def frame(*words):
    size = len(max(words, key=len))
    print('*' * (size + 4))
    for word in words:
        print('* {a:<{b}} *'.format(a=word, b=size))
    print('*' * (size + 4))
frame(p)
```

However the answer is coming as follow if we input abc xyz uxv vxu :

```
*******************
* abc xyz uxv vxu *
*******************
```

while the intended answer should be:

```
*******
* abc *
* xyz *
* uxv *
* vxu *
*******
```

Comment: `frame(p.split(" "))`?

Comment: does not work, I've tried it earlier

Comment: @HamdanAlBalushi I tried Richard answer and it works

Comment: How do you think, what `*` near function argument name does?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p=input("words?")
def frame(words):
    size = len(max(words, key=len))
    print('*' * (size + 4))
    for word in words:
        print(f'* {word} *')
    print('*' * (size + 4))
frame(p.split(" "))
```

From [Olvin Roght's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10824407/olvin-roght) suggestion, I edited the print to use an f-string and changed *words to words since you're not passing a variable number of arguments to the function(?). 
Info on [args](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html)

Here is the output[image]

For strings of different lengths:
(I changed to f-string because I didn't understand the purpose of the format method, but I have tested again and the original print statement posed in the problem works)

```
p=input("words?")
def frame(words):
    size = len(max(words, key=len))
    print('*' * (size + 4))
    for word in words:
        print('* {a:<{b}} *'.format(a=word, b=size))
    print('*' * (size + 4))
frame(p.split(" "))
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Richard, it solved the problem however the * on the end of every word is moving depending on number of strings, any way to keep it fixed all on same line?

Comment: Replace the f-string with your original line print('* {a:<{b}} *'.format(a=word, b=size)), and it will work (I assumed you were not using strings of different lengths between spaces in your input)

Comment: How would you do this in Javascript ? I doubt if there is method like format in JS which takes word and size and prints it. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

p=input("words?")
def frame(words):
size = len(max(words, key=len))
print('*' * (size + 4))
for word in words:
print(f'* {word} *')
print('*' * (size + 4))
frame(p.split(" "))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please add some lines to format your code with some line breaks and a some markdown for the code. Please explain what your code is doing, too. See this link for help: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code - Cheers!